# Using SGD without using sklearn (LogLoss increasing with every epoch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, loss-function, sgd

```
def train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,epochs,alpha,eta0):
    w,b = initialize_weights(X_train[0])
    loss_test=[]
    N=len(X_train)
    for i in range(0,epochs):
        print(i)
        for j in range(N-1):
            grad_dw=gradient_dw(X_train[j],y_train[j],w,b,alpha,N)
            grad_db=gradient_db(X_train[j],y_train[j],w,b)
            w=np.array(w)+(alpha*(np.array(grad_dw)))
            b=b+(alpha*(grad_db))                
               predict2 = []
    for m in range(len(y_test)):
        z=np.dot(w[0],X_test[m])+b
        if sigmoid(z) == 0: # sigmoid(w,x,b) returns 1/(1+exp(-(dot(x,w)+b)))
            predict2.append(0.000001)
        elif sigmoid(z) == 1:
            predict2.append(0.99999)
        else:
            predict2.append(sigmoid(z)) 
            
    loss_test.append(logloss(y_test,predict2))       
    return w,b,loss_test
```

my gradient dw function

```
def gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N):
    dw=[]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        dw.append((x[i]*(y-1/(1+np.exp(abs(w.T[0][i]*x[i]+b)))))+(alpha/N)*(w.T[0][i]))
    return dw
```

My gradient db function:

```
 def gradient_db(x,y,w,b):
        db=0
        for i in range(len(x)):
            db=(y-1/(1+np.exp(abs(w.T[0][i]*x[i]+b))))
        return db
```

My loss function:

```
def logloss(y_true,y_pred):
    loss=0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        loss+=((y_true[i]*math.log10(y_pred[i]))+((1-y_true[i])*math.log10(1-y_pred[i])))
    loss=-1*(1/len(y_true))*loss
    return loss
```

**My problem is after every epoch my loss is increasing. Why?**

**Any Help will be appreciated**

*Thank you*

Comment: I haven't checked your formulas, but I noticed that you add the gradient  in each timestep. The update rule for GD is `w_{t+1} = w_t - \gamma \nabla  \mathcal{L}(w_t)`. The gradient points per definition in the upwards direction of your function. Therefore you need to go in the opposite direction of the gradient to move in the direction of the minimum.

Comment: @Tinu how can i do that ?my w is of size 15.and train is of size 5000.how to do this equation.w_{t+1} = w_t - \gamma \nabla  \mathcal{L}(w_t) .What is t and its length.I am exactly not understanding this part

Comment: All you need to do in your `train` function is to replace the `+` in `w=np.array(w)+(alpha*(np.array(grad_dw)))` and `b=b+(alpha*(grad_db))` with a `-`. If that doesn't work check your formulas, derivations and your code again.

Comment: It increased even more @Tinu

Comment: No Answers yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. The problem was of weight function
> 2. i was taking weight array as of dim(15,1)
> 3. but it should be (15)
> 4. So all the changes need to be done according with it in this code
> 5. Thank You